# Magento-2 How to add website_id column to my custom existing table by Upgrade Schema

Tags: magento2, upgradeschema

I want to add **website_id** column to my custom table with **index** and **foreign** key by **UpgradeSchema**.

It is easy to add by **InstallSchema** but I want to add **website_id** column by **UpgradeSchema** in my existing custom table.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code in your **UpgradeSchema.php** file :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2015 Ihor Vansach (ihor@magefan.com). All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details (http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php).
 *
 */

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

/**
 * Custom Table update
 */
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $setup->startSetup();

        $version = $context->getVersion();
        $connection = $setup->getConnection();
        $tablename = "my_custom_table";
        if (version_compare($version, '1.0.6') < 0) 
        {
            //Custom table
           $connection->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($tablename),
                'website_id',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                    'length' => 5,
                    'comment' =>'Website Id',
                    'unsigned'  => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                ]

            );
            $connection->addIndex(
                $setup->getTable('my_custom_table'),
                $setup->getIdxName($setup->getTable('my_custom_table'),['website_id']),
                ['website_id']
            );
            $connection->addForeignKey(
                    $setup->getFkName($tablename,'website_id','store_website','website_id'),
                    $tablename,
                    'website_id',
                    $setup->getTable('store_website'),
                    'website_id',
                    Table::ACTION_CASCADE 
                );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**Note :**

- I have used my custom existing table called = **my_custom_table** which i have created using **InstallSchema.php** previously and now adding column **website_id** using **UpgradeSchema.php**
- Linked with **website_id** primary key from **store_website** table.
- Update your **module version in module.xml** and same version mention in **UpgradeSchema.php** file to compare.
- Run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** command again and check

Comment: I have added your code but addForeignKey logic wrong. My core store table data also deleted.

Comment: @SHPatel ok got it , for that you can do one thing pass `ACTION_NO_ACTION` in Table parameter of  Foreignkey so it will not delete the core store table data

Comment: I need to delete my website_id once website delete from store_website.

Comment: @SHPatel ok got your point  , and i have updated the answer please check. Actually need to put reverse logic in ForeignKey , First needs to mention custom table and second core table

Comment: Updated answer code is working. but before updated code was very struggle for me because of core admin store delete from core table and site  working stop. 

By the way thanks for answer.

Comment: @SHPatel Yes i understand because it directly deletes your second store. But Happy to know that code is working , Keep helping :)